# Best Way to move files into TrueCrypt partition

Tags: truecrypt

At the moment I try to move ~350GB of data into a truecrypt partition via Windows Explorer on Windows Vista.
Unfortunately the data transfer breaks down frequently.
Is there a workaround? Should I use another way to transfer the data than Windows Explorer? If so what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy is your friend.  There are numerous alternatives, but robocopy is included with Vista and should work fine for your purposes.

Comment: RichCopy is an improvement of RoboCopy...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx